# MS Word to PDF in Magento 2 for uploaded word file

Tags: magento2, pdf

I need to convert word to pdf in magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `PHP Library` from you can manipulate Word file and convert to PDF.

From Here you can download the library https://www.phpdocx.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is open source PHP library we can use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord